# Get Length of a substring in string before certain character Swift

Tags: swift, string

My main string is like this "90000+8000-1000*10". I wanted to find the length of substring that contain number and make it into array. So it will be like this:

```
print(substringLength[0]) //Show 5
print(substringLength[1]) //Show 4
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is signed is fixed?

Comment: @RajaKishan I'm sorry I don't understand. Do you mean the string is fixed or not? If it is then the string is not fixed. it's only example.

Comment: No. I mean in string have +, - and * sign. so it fixed special char in a string ?

Comment: @RajaKishan oh yes! it's only separated only by special character, and I needed to find the length of number value.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543618/14351818

Comment: @FirdaSahidi check out the [description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68956428/5623035) and don't use a bad practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ⚠️ Be aware of using `replacingOccurrences`!

Although this method (mentioned by @Raja Kishan) may work in some cases, it's not forward compatible and will fail if you have unhandled characters (like other expression operators)

---

#### ✅ Just write it as you say it:

```
let numbers = "90000+8000-1000*10".split { !$0.isWholeNumber && $0 != "." }
```

You have the numbers! go ahead and count the length

```
numbers[0].count // show 5
numbers[1].count // shows 4
```

---

#### You can also have the operators like:

```
let operators = "90000+8000-1000*10".split { $0.isWholeNumber || $0 == "." }
```

Comment: I have already mentioned in post for fixed specials characters

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! This works like a charm! @Mojtaba Hosseini!

Comment: This would allow fraction characters as well as many others that are not single digits 0...9

Comment: The Character initializer is pointless/redundant. Swift is a type inferred language.

Comment: You are right about the fraction and I've added the support, but  I don't know if we should drop the support for other languages.

Comment: I agree about supporting other languages but I don't think that would be the expected behavior here. Btw there is a non fraction property called `isWholeNumber` but that would allow 万 as well which means 10_000

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` when the character is not a number.

The 'max splits' method is used for performance, so you don't unnecessarily split part of the input you don't need. There are also preconditions to handle any bad input.

```
func substringLength(of input: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(index >= 0, "Index is negative")
    let sections = input.split(maxSplits: index + 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false) { char in
        !char.isNumber
    }
    precondition(index < sections.count, "Out of range")
    return sections[index].count
}
```

> ```
> let str = "90000+8000-1000*10"
>
> substringLength(of: str, at: 0) // 5
> substringLength(of: str, at: 1) // 4
> substringLength(of: str, at: 2) // 4
> substringLength(of: str, at: 3) // 2
> substringLength(of: str, at: 4) // Precondition failed: Out of range
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If the sign (operator) is fixed then you can replace all signs with a common one sign and split the string by a common sign.

Here is the example

```
extension String {
    func getSubStrings() -> [String] {
        let commonSignStr = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-").replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: "-")
        return commonSignStr.components(separatedBy: "-")
    }
}
```

```
let str = "90000+8000-1000*10"
str.getSubStrings().forEach({print($0.count)})
```

Comment: Try not to extend the general types (like String) for specific use cases. Or at least make it more conventional by asking for characters.

Comment: Why ? Split property also declared in string

Comment: I mean something like: `extension String {
    func getSubStrings(separatedBy separators: [String]) -> [String] {
        var mutatedSelf = self
        for separator in separators {
            mutatedSelf = mutatedSelf.replacingOccurrences(of: separator, with: "-")
        }
        return mutatedSelf.components(separatedBy: "-")
    }
}`

Comment: You are not returning substrings. To return substrings you would need to use the split method. Note that components(separatedBy:) method would also return empty strings if you have a string that ends with an operator or have two operators in a row ("+-", "--", "++" or "--").

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that the separators are not numbers, regardless of what they are.

```
let str = "90000+8000-1000*10"
let arr = str.split { !$0.isNumber }
let substringLength = arr.map { $0.count }

print(substringLength) // [5, 4, 4, 2]
print(substringLength[0]) //Show 5
print(substringLength[1]) //Show 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [isNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127015-isnumber) Character property. This would allow fraction characters as well as many others that are not single digits 0...9.

> **Discussion**
> For example, the following characters all represent numbers:
> “7” (U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN)
> “⅚” (U+215A VULGAR FRACTION FIVE SIXTHS)
> “㊈” (U+3288 CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH NINE)
> “” (U+1D7E0 MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT EIGHT)
> “๒” (U+0E52 THAI DIGIT TWO)

```
let numbers = "90000+8000-1000*10".split { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }   // ["90000", "8000", "1000", "10"]

let numbers2 = "90000+8000-1000*10 ५ ๙ 万 ⅚  ๒ ".split { !("0"..."9" ~= $0) }   // ["90000", "8000", "1000", "10"]
```